# Can realm store 2 GB of data in android using an external SD?

Tags: android, sqlite, realm

I want to create an app with a lot of local data, this app will insert a *.txt with 2GB of data in columns. I want to use Realm for this app because then I need to do searches, Is it possible?.
I would like to meet other options.

Comment: You could look at documentation. https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#current-limitations

Comment: Of course, it depends on how you are going to use your texts. If you are not going to query the texts, it might be better to leave them as text files on the file system, and store the file names in a Realm.

Comment: Please explain further what you mean by _insert a *.txt_ as we can't tell if you want to have a single, searchable text field, or if that is 2GB of columns of data.

Comment: The *.txt file has various columns, I will need to insert in a db. after that, The user could search by difference column. the specific question is if realm can support 2 gb of data in total.

Comment: I think maybe you don't understand that Realm IS the database. You can definitely download 2 GB of data and then put it into a Realm database, but not all in one piece (that's not how databases work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Realm's Docs:
"NSData and String properties cannot hold data exceeding 16MB in size. To store larger amounts of data, either break it up into 16MB chunks or store it directly on the file system, storing paths to these files in the realm. An exception will be thrown at runtime if your app attempts to store more than 16MB in a single property."

It's #3 in the "General Limits" section. https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#current-limitations